# Windows server 2012 can't access HTTP(80) Websites

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

I have a problem whereby my Server 2012 R2 server cannot access sites on Port 80.

- Server 2012 R2
- Firewall disabled.
- Cannot communicate on Port 80
- Can ping websites without issue
- Cannot Telnet to sites.
- CAN access 443 (https) - hence the misnomer "But GOOGLE WORKS." since Google defaults to HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

This was not the answer - port 80 was STILL not working on the server.

In this case, another technician had previously configured a NAT to the server for 8080--80 - causing 80 to be mapped on the outside to port 8080.

The SonicWall also creates loopback and reflexive rules, which caused port 80 traffic to die from the server, as it would not go out on the correct port.

Disabling the reflexive rule corrected the issue permanently
.

Answer (score 0):

**All I had to do was restart the Windows Firewall service, which restored port 80 outbound.**

I realize this will likely be a quirk on my end, but felt the need to at least throw the answer in the mix, since it worked for me.